# Find record position in Linq2Sql or Entity framework query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to implement [IBindingListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglistview(v=vs.110).aspx) that will work with any Linq query as data source, but I'm stuck on the implementation of [Find(PropertyDescriptor, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method which should find position of the record containg some value in specific property.

I don't want to iterate over all records in memory. I want database to do it.

Unfortunately Linq doesn't support row_number() SQL function and I'm unable to find any other way to do it while preserving ordering and filtering.

In other words:
Given

```
class Entity
{
   public string StringProperty {get; set;}
   public int IntProperty {get; set;}
   public string StringProperty2 {get; set;}
}

|StringProperty | IntProperty | StringProperty2|
|ccc            | 102         | value 2        |
|aaa            | 100         | value 0        |
|ddd            | 103         | value 3        |
|aaa            | 101         | value 1        |
```

and query

```
var query = from e in Entities
            where e.IntProperty > 100
            orderby e.StringProperty
```

Which gives me

```
|StringProperty | IntProperty | StringProperty2|
|bbb            | 101         | value 1        |
|ccc            | 102         | value 2        |
|ddd            | 103         | value 3        |
```

Find() with arguments `StringProperty2 = 'value 2'` should return 1 (0 based index), but it should be found using Linq so that it will be executed in database.

I don't have a problem if there will be 2 or 3 queries executed, but please don't assume I know anything about primary keys or specific Linq provider. We can assume that if Linq to SQL or Entity Framework is able to translate something to SQL than it can be used.

How can I implement IBindingListView.Find() method that works on any Linq query as a data source?

Comment: But it's a bit strange to go back to the database to find what you can easily get from the local list.

Comment: @Arnold unless you have million records which you want to show in the grid or your code is in the layer that shouldn't know anything about GUI paging etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda expression form for capture row data and row index.
Example:

```
var query = youCollection
            .Select((r, i) => new {Row = r, Index = i});
```

Comment: index only works if we fetch all the data without filter, if we use filter, the index not show the position of record. but the loaded data within the memory.